# Cocoa touch code to set NSInteger to number in a text field

Tags: cocoa-touch, numbers, textfield, nsinteger

I need to set an NSInteger to the number in a text field. And I've googled it and could not find any answer. Does anybody know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger x = [textField.text integerValue];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how you would do that with a subtraction method like this 
    NSInteger givedback = givedback - [self.textField.text integerValue];                                                         When I run the app and enter a number in comes up with a crazy number

Comment: Hard to say from here. Would have to see it more in context. My recommendation when debugging is to make simple expressions instead of compound, because it's easier to examine in the debugger. For instance, assign the integerValue of textField to "x", then do the math of 'givedback - x'. Then you can see if perhaps x is wrong and the problem is in extraction and conversion there. You might even try assigning textField.text to a local NSString, seeing the true string value, etc.. Just something for you to debug.

Comment: @Programer Does XCode generate warning about `NSInteger givedback = givedback - [self.textField.text integerValue];` code? Because you're creating variable and then using this variable in it's own initialization.

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk Yes It does. It works when I try to minus it with an number

Comment: @Programer if this was the correct answer, could you come back and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

John C. Daub answer is perfect. I would add this also:

```
NSInteger x = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[field.text integerValue]] integerValue];
```

The advantage of `NSNumber` is that if you want to pass this integer into dicitonary, NSNumber helps.

On the other hand a call to `integerValue` would be sufficient.

Comment: To be pedeantic about it, it should be +numberWithInteger:.

Comment: did you mean `NSNumber x = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[field.text integerValue]];` ?

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk, left hand side will be NSInteger. so it should be: `NSInteger x = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[field.text integerValue]];` for this case atleast. Other you can take NSNumber on the left side as well.

Comment: @NeverHopeless `NSNumber` is an object and `NSInteger` is a simple type
Only way `NSInteger` could be on the left side: `NSInteger x = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[field.text integerValue]] integerValue];` wich looks kinda overhead

Comment: It is an overhead if you are going to use it for NSInteger on the left side but it is useful when you pass it in dictionary. There you need type `id`.

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, the original code was taking the -integerValue of the text and creating the NSNumber using +numberWithInt:. It's a mixing of "int" and "NSInteger" which, strictly speaking, aren't the same thing.

Comment: @NeverHopeless I mean you can't assign `NSNumber` to `NSInteger`

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk, with an overhead, you can. My post was missing last call of `integerValue`